# ¿Que es un header?

Tags: c++

Holaa, soy nuevo. Mi profe siempre me hacia hacer los ejercicios de C++ en un solo archivo, pero ahora estamos aprendiendo a compilar mas de un archivo. Cuando creo el proyecto se me crea una carpeta de Source y otra de Header. Mi pregunta es: ¿Que parte del código es la que va en Header o .h? ¿Que es lo que debería poner ahí? Si tienen algún ejemplo muy básico me ayudaria mucho más.
Gracias!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ funciona de una manera peculiar. Por eso me parece buena idea comenzar mencionando algunas cosas del proceso de compilación del lenguaje.

Están los archivos `.cpp` que contienen código. Cada uno de ellos se compila por separado en lo que se llama **unidad de traducción**.

Una vez se compiló todo el código, el linker procede a unir las unidades de traducción.

---

Sucede que hay dos maneras de indicar la existencia de una función.

Definiéndola:

```
int restar(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}
```

O declarándola (la función sin cuerpo):

```
int restar(int a, int b);
```

En el primer caso le estás diciendo al compilador *"aquí está la función `restar`"*.

En el segundo *"hay una función `restar` en algún lado"*. El te creerá sin quejarse.

Pero el linker no lo hará. Buscará una función `restar` definida en el código. Si no la encuentra, obtendrás un error y no se generará el ejecutable final.

Cabe mencionar que **definir** o **implementar** una función son sinónimos.

---

Otro error que puede dar el linker es cuándo tienes más de una implementación o llamado como **símbolos duplicados**. Pues no sabe a cuál de todas te refieres. Como cuando alguna vez en tu vida estuviste con 2 o más personas tenían el mismo nombre y tenías que ser claro en cuanto a cuál te referías. Un ejemplo:

```
// Ambas funciones hacen lo mismo a su manera.
// Aunque podrían hacer cosas diferentes.

int restar(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}

int restar(int a, int b){
    return a + (-b);
}
```

---

Ten en cuenta que el compilador procesa el archivo secuencialmente. Por lo tanto, siempre hay que indicarle que existe una función para poder usarla, antes del lugar donde la llamas.

Ahora que esto está claro, veamos unos ejemplos.

Puedes definirla antes de la función `main`:

```
int restar(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}

int main(){
    restar(4, 2);
}
```

Después de ella, pero declarándola antes:

```
int restar(int a, int b);

int main(){
    restar(8, 3);
}

int restar(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}
```

En varios archivos:

```
// main.cpp
int restar(int a, int b);

int main(){
    restar(9, 4);
}

// operaciones.cpp
int restar(int a, int b){
    return a - b;
}
```

Los 3 ejemplos funcionarán si los pruebas. En el caso del último, debes asegurarte compilar ambos archivos.

Si estás usando un IDE como Visual Studio, con incluirlos en el proyecto debería bastar puesto que el se encarga de la parte complicada.

---

Llegado a este punto, has visto que no he usado ningún archivo `.h`. Probablemente pienses que no son necesarios. Es cierto, no lo son.

Lo que sucede es que el número de declaraciones aumentará a la par de la cantidad de funciones. Además es probable que quieres usar las mismas funciones en otros archivos.

Sería engorroso tener que estar escribiendo en cada archivo `.cpp` las declaraciones.

## Conclusión

La función de los archivos `.h` es contener todas las declaraciones. En conjunto con las directivas de preprocesador, específicamente `#include` le hacen la vida más fácil al programador.

Algunos enlaces de interés:

- Playlist de C++ de The Cherno: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb
- Preprocesador: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor
- Fases de traducción: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/875489/13419694

Comment: Hola @Mateo!! Me encantó tu explicación! Fuiste clarísimo! Me hiciste entender todo de raíz! Con los ejemplos y todo. Muchas muchas gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Antes de explicar lo que es una cabecera, debemos entender los conceptos de declarar y definir.

- **Declarar**: Con una declaración se le dice al compilador que un símbolo existe, pero no se entra en detalles de cómo es ese símbolo.

  ```
  void funcion(); // Se declara una función llamada 'funcion' pero sin darle cuerpo.
  class Clase;    // Se declara una clase llamada 'Clase' pero sin darle cuerpo.
  struct Objeto
  {
       // Se declara una función miembro de 'Objeto' llamada 'funcion' pero sin darle cuerpo.
       void funcion();
  };
  ```
- **Definir**: Con una definición se le dice al compilador que un símbolo existe y se le dan todos los detalles de cómo es ese símbolo, si no estaba declarada cuenta como declaración.

  ```
  // Se define la función 'funcion' con un cuerpo de función.
  void funcion() { std::cout << "Hola mundo!\n"; }
  // Se define la clase 'Clase' dándole cuerpo (en este caso vacío).
  class Clase {};
  struct Objeto
  {
       // Se define la función 'Objeto::funcion' con un cuerpo de función.
       void funcion() { std::cout << "Patatas fritas, que ricas!\n"; }
  };
  ```

En general, los archivos de cabecera se usan para declaraciones mientras que los de código se usan para definiciones.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me sirvió un montón! @PaperBirdMaster