# Error de undefined Reference to .... en clases de c++

Tags: c++, poo

Estoy con el problema de **undefined reference to**, y la verdad no tengo ni idea de por qué está ocurriendo.

El error que me da el compilador (mingw por cierto) es el siguiente:

> c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGz93xA.o: in function `escribir(Archivo)':
> C:/Users/cuent/Proyectos  /Proyecto_Primer_Parcial_Estructura_de_Datos_II/src/main.cpp:88: undefined reference to `Paciente::Paciente(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, bool, bool, char*, char*)'
> c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/cuent/Proyectos/Proyecto_Primer_Parcial_Estructura_de_Datos_II/src/main.cpp:90: undefined reference to `Paciente::toStringabi:cxx11'
> c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/cuent/Proyectos/Proyecto_Primer_Parcial_Estructura_de_Datos_II/src/main.cpp:90: undefined reference to `Archivo::escribirRegistro(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)'
> c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\cuent\AppData\Local  \Temp\ccGz93xA.o: in function `main':
> C:/Users/cuent/Proyectos/Proyecto_Primer_Parcial_Estructura_de_Datos_II/src/main.cpp:97: undefined reference to `Archivo::Archivo(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >)'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Literalmente me da **undefined reference to** a todos los métodos de las dos clases (Paciente y Archivo) que estoy llamando desde el main y realmente no sé por qué, ya que tanto en los .h y .cpp he definido los métodos correctamente (o bueno, eso creo yo).

Cabe recalcar que estoy usando el editor de código VS Code y la extensión de C/C++ Extension Pack que brinda Microsoft; además tengo los header y los .cpp en carpetas distintas, esta sería su organización:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les proporciono el código de los header y los archivos cpp de cada clase como el main:

**Archivo.h**

```
#ifndef ARCHIVO_H
#define ARCHIVO_H


#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Archivo
{
private:
    std::string ruta;

public:
    /* Constructores*/
    Archivo(std::string ruta);

    /* Setters*/

    void setRuta(std::string ruta);

    /* Getters*/

    std::string getRuta();

    /* Metodos*/

    std::vector<std::string> leerRegistros();
    void elimimarResgistro(std::string regitro);
    void escribirRegistro(std::string regitro);

};

#endif
```

**Archivo.cpp**

```
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "../include/Archivo.h"
    
    
    using namespace std;
    
    /* constructor*/
    
    Archivo::Archivo(string ruta)
    {
        this->ruta = ruta;
    }
    
    /* Setters*/
    
    void Archivo::setRuta(string ruta)
    {
        this->ruta = ruta;
    }
    
    /* Getters*/
    
    string Archivo::getRuta()
    {
        return this->ruta;
    }
    
    /* Metodos de la clase*/
    
    vector<string> Archivo::leerRegistros()
    {
        ifstream archivoAbierto(this->getRuta());
    
        if(!archivoAbierto.is_open())
        {
            cerr << "Archivo no encontrado" << endl;
            return;
        }
    
        vector<string> registros;
        string registro;
    
        while(getline(archivoAbierto, registro))
        {
            registros.push_back(registro);
        }
    
        archivoAbierto.close();
    
        return registros;
    }
    
    void Archivo::escribirRegistro(string registro)
    {
    
        ofstream arhivoAbierto(this->getRuta(), std::ios::app); // Para que escriba siempre al final.
    
        if(!arhivoAbierto.is_open())
        {
            cerr << "Archivo no encontrado" << endl;
            return;
        }
    
        arhivoAbierto << registro;
    
        arhivoAbierto.close();
    
    }
    
    void Archivo::elimimarResgistro(string registro){

}
```

**Paciente.h**

```
#ifndef PACIENTE_H
#define PACIENTE_H

#include <cstring>
#include <string>
class Paciente
{
private:
    char identidad[13];
    char sexo[1];
    char domicilio[80];
    char centroDeSalud[30];
    char fecha[10];
    bool ocupaDesparacitacion;
    bool ocupaVacunacion;
    char vacunas[150];
    char desparacitante[30];

public:
    Paciente(char iden[], char sex[], char dom[], char centro[], char fec[], bool desp, bool vac, char v[], char d[]);

    /* Setters*/
    void setIdentidad(char iden[13]);
    void setSexo(char sex[1]);
    void setDomicilio(char dom[80]);
    void setCentroDeSalud(char centro[30]);
    void setFecha(char fec[10]);
    void setOcupaDesparacitacion(bool desp);
    void setOcupaVacunacion(bool vac);
    void setVacunas(char v[150]);
    void setDesparacitante(char d[30]);

    /*Getters*/
    char getIdentidad();
    char getSexo();
    char getDomicilio();
    char getCentroDeSalud();
    char getFecha();
    bool getOcupaDesparacitacion();
    bool getOcupaVacunacion();
    char getVacunas();
    char getDesparacitante();

    /* Metodos */
    std::string toString();
};

#endif
```

**Archivo Paciente.cpp**

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include "../include/Paciente.h"


/* Constructores de Paciente*/
 Paciente::Paciente(char iden[], char sex[], char dom[], char centro[], char fec[], bool desp, bool vac, char v[], char d[]) {
            strcpy(identidad, iden);
            strcpy(sexo, sex);
            strcpy(domicilio, dom);
            strcpy(centroDeSalud, centro);
            strcpy(fecha, fec);
            ocupaDesparacitacion = desp;
            ocupaVacunacion = vac;
            strcpy(vacunas, v);
            strcpy(desparacitante, d);
}

/* Setters*/
void Paciente::setIdentidad(char iden[13])
{
    strcpy(identidad, iden);
}

void Paciente::setSexo(char sex[1])
{
    strcpy(sexo, sex);
}

void Paciente::setDomicilio(char dom[80])
{
    strcpy(domicilio, dom);
}

void Paciente::setCentroDeSalud(char centro[30])
{
    strcpy(centroDeSalud, centro);
}

void Paciente::setFecha(char fec[10])
{
    strcpy(fecha, fec);
}

void Paciente::setOcupaDesparacitacion(bool desp)
{
    ocupaDesparacitacion = desp;
}

void Paciente::setOcupaVacunacion(bool vac)
{
    ocupaVacunacion = vac;
}

void Paciente::setVacunas(char v[150])
{
    strcpy(vacunas, v);
}

void Paciente::setDesparacitante(char d[30])
{
    strcpy(desparacitante, d);
}

/* Getters*/

char Paciente::getIdentidad()
{
    return identidad[13];
}

char Paciente::getSexo()
{
    return sexo[1];
}

char Paciente::getDomicilio()
{
    return domicilio[80];
}

char Paciente::getCentroDeSalud()
{
    return centroDeSalud[30];
}

char Paciente::getFecha()
{
    return fecha[10];
}

bool Paciente::getOcupaDesparacitacion()
{
    return ocupaDesparacitacion;
}

bool Paciente::getOcupaVacunacion()
{
    return ocupaVacunacion;
}

char Paciente::getVacunas()
{
    return vacunas[150];
}

char Paciente::getDesparacitante()
{
    return desparacitante[30];
}

/* Metodos */

std::string Paciente::toString()
{
    char cadena[350];
    sprintf(cadena, " | %13s | %1s | %80s | %30s | %10s | %2s | %2s | %150s | %30s |", this->getIdentidad(), this->getSexo(), this->getDomicilio(), this->getCentroDeSalud(), this->getFecha(), this->getOcupaDesparacitacion(), this->getOcupaVacunacion(), this->getVacunas(), this->getDesparacitante());
    return cadena;
}
```

**Archivo Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "../include/Archivo.h"
#include "../include/Paciente.h"

using namespace std;

int menuPrincipal()
{
    int opcion;

    cout << "***REGISTRO DE VACUNCION DE PACIENTES A NIVEL NACIONAL***\n"
         << "**********MENU PRINCIPAL DE APLICACION**********\n"
         << "1. Leer Registros de Pacientes Vacunado dunrante la Jornada\n" 
         << "2. Guardar Nuevo paciente Vacunado\n"
         << "3. Eliminar Registro de Paciente\n"
         << "4. Manipular lista de disponibles\n"
         << "5. Compactar Archivo de Registros\n"
         << "6. MAnejar Indice Primario\n"
         << "Elija una Opcion Para continuar (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 o 6) : ";
    do
    {
        cin >> opcion;
        if (opcion < 1 || opcion > 6)
        {
            cout << "\nOpcion invalida, intente de nuevo. (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 o 6) : ";
        }
        
    } while (opcion < 1 || opcion > 6);

    return opcion;
    
}

void leerDatos()
{

}

void escribir(Archivo archivoPacientes)
{
    char identidad[13];
    char sexo[1];
    char domicilio[80];
    char centroDeSalud[30];
    char fecha[10];
    bool ocupaDesparacitacion;
    bool ocupaVacunacion;
    char vacunas[150];
    char desparacitante[30];


    cout << "Ingrese la identidad del paciente (sin guiones): ";
    cin >> identidad;

    cout << "Ingrese el sexo del paciente (M o F): ";
    cin >> sexo;

    cout << "Ingrese el domicilio del paciente: ";
    cin.ignore(); 
    cin.getline(domicilio, 80);

    cout << "Ingrese el centro de salud del paciente: ";
    cin.getline(centroDeSalud, 30);

    cout << "Ingrese la fecha del registro (DD/MM/AAAA): ";
    cin >> fecha;

    cout << "El paciente ocupa desparasitación (1 = Sí, 0 = No): ";
    cin >> ocupaDesparacitacion;

    cout << "El paciente ocupa vacunación (1 = Sí, 0 = No): ";
    cin >> ocupaVacunacion;

    if (ocupaVacunacion)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el tipo de vacunas necesarias (separadas por comas): ";
        cin.ignore(); 
        cin.getline(vacunas, 150);
    }

    if (ocupaDesparacitacion)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el tipo de desparacitante necesario: ";
        cin.getline(desparacitante, 30);
    }

    Paciente nuevoPaiente(identidad, sexo, domicilio, centroDeSalud, fecha, ocupaDesparacitacion, ocupaVacunacion, vacunas, desparacitante);

    archivoPacientes.escribirRegistro(nuevoPaiente.toString());

}

int main()
{
    
    Archivo archivoPacientes("./data/Pacientes.txt");

    int opcion; // Almacena la opcion que seleccione el usuario

    opcion = menuPrincipal();

    switch (opcion)
    {
        case 1:  escribir(archivoPacientes); break;
        case 2:  /* code */ break;
        case 3:  /* code */ break;
        case 4:  /* code */ break;
        case 5:  /* code */ break;
        case 6:  /* code */ break;
    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola JoseAguilar, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina la imagen, y agrega tu mensaje de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias.

Comment: La solución es clara, pero por desgracia la captura de pantalla del error no lo es. Cambia la captura por texto y te compartimos la solución.

Comment: Esto no es un problema del código. El problema está en cómo lo compilas. Seguramente te esté faltando enlazar las 2 unidades de traducción.

Comment: @Mateo un gusto, a que te refieres con enlazar las dos unidades de traducción????, estoy un poco confundido al respecto.

Comment: Supongo que estás comenzando en C++. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65557/169744) puedes aprender más al respecto. Y [aquí sobre headers](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/519627/169744).

Answer (score 1):

> Literalmente me da **undefined reference to** a todos los métodos de las dos clases (Paciente y Archivo) que estoy llamando desde el main y realmente no sé por qué, ya que tanto en los .h y .cpp he definido los métodos correctamente

El problema no es la definición, el problema es que no compilas esos archivos y por ello el enlazador no puede encontrar el cuerpo de las funciones. Si revisas la línea de comandos verás que **sólo** estás pasando `main.cpp` cuando deberías estar pasando también `Archivo.cpp` y `Paciente.cpp`.

> ¿Cómo hacer que el compilador también compile las otras dos clases junto al `main`?

En otros IDE como Visual Studio basta con añadir los archivos a compilar al proyecto (como ya has hecho), pero VS Code no funciona así,  puedes ver una guía de uso en [este enlace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) del cuál podemos leer esta información (traducción mía):

> ##### Modificando tasks.json
>
> Puedes modificar tu `tasks.json` para compilar múltiples archivos C++ usando un argumento como `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"` en lugar de `${file}`. Esto compilará todos los archivos `.cpp` en tu carpeta actual.

Comment: Hola, acabo de ver tu respuesta, y disculpa totalmente mi ignorancia al respecto, pero realmente no tengo idea de como hacer que el compilador también compile las otras dos clases junto al main, agradecería si me guiaran al respecto.