# ¿Cómo debería establecer "proyectos" en VIsualStudioCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio, funciones, codeblocks, modulos

He estado trabajando en un curso donde usamos Codeblocks que tiene la opción de usar proyectos, lo que de alguna forma junta los archivos que estamos usando y los compila todos juntos, hace poco implementaron una funcionalidad que es las cabeceras o headers (archivo.h) que se juntan con los archivos relacionados (archivo.c) mas que nada para hacer funciones publicas y privadas, mi problema es que en VisualStudio yo no puedo crear un proyecto y cuando compilo simplemente me compila el header con mi main.c, y se salta completamente el cuerpo de mi función

[image: Este es el main.c]

[image: header.h]

[image: El archivo relacionado con el mismo nombre en .c]

[image: Aca esta el mensaje de error, no tira que esta indefinido, pero no compila]

Todos los archivos mostrados se encentran en la misma carpeta pero en ningún momento se genera un proyecto, porque no encuentro la opción o me falta algo, si alguien sabe como es en visual mejor que mejor
Usamos el compilador de embarcadero tecnologies "Embarcadero C++ 7.30 for Win32"

Comment: En Visual Studio Code lo más cercano que tienes a un proyecto es utilizar directamente la línea de comandos, o automatizar el proceso con un tasks.json. Como alternativa puedes usar cmake.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error de undefined Reference to .... en clases de c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/593064/error-de-undefined-reference-to-en-clases-de-c)